# TS Error - Create Custom React Alert Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-component

I am trying to create a custom react material ui alert component that I can call on different pages by simply passing in the text and severity as parameters. I am trying to use this:

```
export default function CustomAlert(severity: string, text: string){
    <Alert style={{width:'50%'}} severity={severity}> {text}</Alert>
}
```

but I keep getting an error on the first severity word `severity={severity}`that:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"error" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | undefined'.ts(2322)
Alert.d.ts(25, 3): The expected type comes from property 'severity' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AlertProps'
```

How could I fix this? Or is there an alternative method to customise this component?

Edit: I am still not being able to use it in my other page:

```
  function StatusMessage(){
    if (isRemoved){
      return (
      <Alert style={{width:'25%'}} severity="success"> User Removed</Alert>
        )
      }
      else{
        if(errorMessage!=''){
        if (errorMessage.includes(`Couldn't find user`)){
          return (
            <div>
            {/* <Alert style={{width:'25%'}} severity="error"> Couldn't Find User</Alert> */}
            <CustomAlert></CustomAlert>
            </div>
              )
        }       
      }}
  }
```

I get errors on CustomAlert that:

```
JSX element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.ts(2605)
Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & "success") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "info") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "warning") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "error")'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type '"error"'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Alert` can only take a finite number of strings or undefined, so you have to be explicit that your passes string is of this type.

```js
type Severity = "error" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | undefined;

export default function CustomAlert(severity: Severity, text = "Sorry"){
    <Alert style={{width:'50%'}} severity={severity}> {text}</Alert>
}
```

Now, the TS compiler knows for a fact that `severity` will be one of the union type `Severity`, and shouldn't throw an error.

Comment: The ```severity="error"``` in the parameter was just to test. Originally, I want the parameter to be just severity so that I can pass it from other pages. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Makes sense, but my response still holds. In fact, it's now even more obvious that the compiler would be upset--it does not allow for a wider type when the Alert takes a narrower type.

Comment: but then how exactly should I write parameters? It won't always be an "error"

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the type Severity thing. Makes sense. But I am still not able to use this into my other page. It gives me errors when I call this component. Updated qs

Comment: Not sure if it's because of the other page's code or this one. But I am already using a  return() so don't get the error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it using AlertColor type from '@mui/material/Alert'

```
import MuiAlert, { AlertProps, AlertColor } from '@mui/material/Alert';

interface INotificacao {
    texto:string,
    duracao:number,
    tipo: AlertColor /* <--- type here */
}
```